# Unable to pause the running batch file for waiting user input intermediately

Tags: batch-file, dos, prompt

I couldn't able to pause the running batch file for asking user input intermediately. I tried the commands like `PAUSE` and `SET /P aaa="Press enter to exit"` and also as following but **nothing worked out**.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /p aaa="Press enter to exit"

ECHO you typed %aaa%

PAUSE
```

My batch file internally invokes another batch to build all visual studio projects under the root of the baseline.

One of the project build is getting failed and finally it returns '1' as *BUILD FAILED* to the main batch file processor. This terminates the MS DOS console immediately and not waiting for user input.

I'm unable to see the MS DOS console window with the end results.

There are various steps to see the end results(Writing the execution output to a text file as like `C:\CurrentApp\MyBuild>ABC.bat MyApp.New.BUILD > output.txt`) but **i would like to see in MS DOS console screen itself with blinking cursor waiting for any user input key**.

My batch file looks like:

```
cd C:\CurrentApp\MyBuild

ABC.bat MyApp.New.BUILD 

SET /p aaa="Press enter key to exit"

PAUSE

@ECHO OFF

SET /p aaa="Press enter key to exit"

ECHO you typed %aaa%

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must call your second batch: `call ABC.bat MyApp.New.BUILD`. Otherwise control passes to ABC.bat but never returns so your `pause` is never executed. You may think of it as of ABC.bat overwriting your current batch contents and then executing itself.